# Segmentation fault: 11 when attempting to codesign .app

Tags: xcode, macos, codesign

I haven't been able to find a definition for this error in relation to codesigning. I'm really quite stumped as of what to do.

The error occurs when attempting to execute this command line:

```
codesign -s "Developer ID Application: Name (ID)" -fv --deep Application.app/
```

System:

XCode 6.2 on Yosemite 10.10.3

I've reinstalled XCode, still without any luck. This is for a desktop application.

Apologies if this is a silly question!

Comment: having the same issue here today.
10.10.3
XCode 6.3

Comment: Have you found a solution? I got the issue initially with 6.3, reverted to 6.2 as above and the issue is still there.

Comment: have you checked if your certificate has expired?

Comment: here is a related discussion that might help us
https://devforums.apple.com/message/1124508

Comment: The loop in that discussion worked for me, except I had to first copy my .app, and in the loop if codesign failed, delete the .app and copy a fresh version into place before trying to codesign again.  Seems codesign is not atomic (I assume that's a separate bug).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A solution I found [on the Apple forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/65055) worked for me: first, run the following command to find your identity's hex ID:

```
$ security find-identity -v
1) A048017A43F8C9C993128B0101B81CD07049601E "lldb_codesign"
...
```

Then you can use that hex identifier to sign:

```
codesign -s A048017A43F8C9C993128B0101B81CD07049601E /usr/local/bin/gdb
```

Some other tips I came across while debugging this:

- You have to give the full path to the binary (`/usr/local/bin/gdb`, not just `gdb`).  It won't look on the PATH, I assume for security reasons.
- You have to run the codesign as root if the directory your binary is in is not user-owned.

Comment: This worked for me on a Jenkins build Mac mini without adding the timestamp option. I also needed to clear out my existing build artifacts. I had just recently updated this to MacOS Sierra and latest XCode 8.3.2. I have not tried this, but wonder if also reloading the certificate after upgrade might help.

Answer (score 6):

passing `--timestamp=none` seems to make the crash go away. In this case, check the network settings, `codesign` may be unable to reach e.g. the timeserver.

Comment: ...except now your app's signature will break as soon as your certificate expires. (But this is actually a good lead to what the real problem is. Maybe it crashes when the timestamp server is down?)

Comment: It crashes if there is an issue with connecting to the server. For me it crashes because I'm behind a firewall that blocks all internet on my build server.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this in Xcode 8.3.2 when I inadvertently wound up with duplicates of my signing certificates. @kristina's answer gave me the clue; `$ security find-identity -v` showed me two entries with identical hashes. I fixed it by deleting the first certificate in the list with that hash, via:

`$ sudo security delete-certificate -Z <SHA hash>`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me the reason was that I wasn't connected to internet, so probably it was trying to connect a time server because of `--timestamp`, and it failed.

Restoring an internet connection solved it.