# MacOS codesign command on Bitrise failure: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: macos, code-signing, codesign, bitrise

For some reason, I need to run a manual code signing for my macos app on [Bitrise](https://www.bitrise.io). When doing that with the following command:

```
codesign --deep --force --verify --verbose --sign "Developer ID Application: Name (ID)" "MyApp.app"
```

It always returned with the error:

```
line 11:  3043 Segmentation fault: 11
```

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While looking for possible solutions I came across these two posts:

[Segmentation fault: 11 when attempting to codesign .app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29687605/segmentation-fault-11-when-attempting-to-codesign-app)

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/65055

They helped me to find a solution to my issue. The answer marked as correct at the first link states that:

```
--timestamp=none
```

would fix it which was not true for me. But the second answer, as well as the solution mentioned in the second link, contains the correct hint.

I needed to sign with hex identifier and not with the certificate name.

You can get the hex identifier for your certificates executing this command:

```
security find-identity -p codesigning
```

Using the hex identifier returned for my certificate this is the command I need to run on Bitrise in order to sign MyApp.app

```
codesign --deep --force --verify --verbose -s <<hex identifier>> "MyApp.app"
```

Be aware that the order of the options is also important. '-s' had to be the last option for me.

(And remember to include the Bitrise workflow step 'Certificate and profile installer')

===Edit===

I'm talking about MacOS Sierra stack here.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution @Thor_Bux

Just one note: this is not bitrise specific, but macOS Sierra specific. A couple of keychain/signing related things changed in Sierra, which worked (a bit differently) on El Capitan. It's important to note, as on bitrise.io you can select both Sierra and El Capitan stacks.

Comment: The reason why I explicitly mentioned Bitrise here is that this issue does not occur on my local Mac which also runs Sierra. Thanks for mentioning that I should include the MacOS version.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by signing with the hex id of the certificate instead.

You can find the HEX ID by running:
`security find-identity -v`

Credit Here: -- [Segmentation fault: 11 when attempting to codesign .app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29687605/segmentation-fault-11-when-attempting-to-codesign-app)